# Backslash (\") issue with fgetcsv() while importing a csv file in php

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

Backslash (\") problem encounter while doing this example of csv import.

here is my 2 input lines from csv

> "Travel_and_Work_en.pdf",840722,3/22/2007 10:57 AM,10/10/2007 12:00
>   AM,10/10/2007 9:00 AM,".pdf","e:\"
>
> "._.Trashes",4096,10/12/2010 4:55 PM,12/8/2014 12:00 AM,11/13/2014
>   3:00 AM,".Trashes","e:\"

with this code, I'm getting the output(edited array) as shown below,

```
while (($csv_data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',')) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($csv_data );
}
```

Output

```
Array (
    [filename] => Travel_and_Work_en.pdf
    [file_size] => 840722
    [modified] => 3/22/2007 10:57 AM
    [accessed] => 10/10/2007 12:00 AM
    [created] => 10/10/2007 9:00 AM
    [extension] => .pdf
    [full_path] => e:\" ._.Trashes"

}
```

The problem here is, the second line 1st field merge with the 1st line last field, I think its because of `\"`at the end, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: what have you tried so far to solve it? If you think it is because of the `\"`, why do you not try to escape it? Instead of using `print_r` to debug, use `var_dump`

Comment: @RonniSkansing Yeah I tried the escaping thing with this code, while (($csv_data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',',  '"', '\\')) !== FALSE) {}, but doesn't seems to work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to use double quote as escape symbol.

```
while (($csv_data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '"', '"')) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($csv_data);
}
```

But you must be sure that you do not have double quotes inside your fields.